# Paginated Gitlab API with Reactor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor, gitlab-api

I am working on a piece of Kotlin code that uses the reactor framework to implement calls to the Gitlab commits API.
The commits API is paginated. The function that I'm struggling with retrieves commits "between" two specified commit hashes.

The function works fine as long as it can actually retrieve any commits, but fails if it can't find results. It then fails with
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Reached end of commit log`.

I tried replacing the line `.switchIfEmpty(Flux.error(RuntimeException("Reached end of commit log.")))` with `.switchIfEmpty(Flux.empty())`, but that generates an endless loop.

I don't quite grasp the nesting of multiple fluxes, which makes it hard for me to debug. I would very much appreciate any hints as to how to solve this problem.

```
fun getCommits(fromCommit: String, toCommit: String): Iterable<Commit> {
    val commits = Flux.concat(Flux.generate<Flux<GitLabCommit>, Int>({ 1 }) { state, sink ->
        val page = client.get()
                .uri("/projects/{name}/repository/commits?page=$state&per_page=100")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux<GitLabCommit>()
                .doOnError({
                    LOGGER.warn("Could not retrieve commits for project '$name': ${it.message}")
                    sink.next(Flux.just(GitLabCommit("xxxxx", "Could not retrieve all commits for project '$name'")))
                    sink.complete()
                })
                .onErrorReturn(GitLabCommit("xxxxx", "Could not retrieve all commits for project '$name'"))
                .switchIfEmpty(Flux.error(RuntimeException("Reached end of commit log.")))

        sink.next(page)
        return@generate state + 1
    })


    return commits
            // The Gitlab API returns commits from newest to oldest
            .skipWhile { !it.id.startsWith(toCommit) } //inclusive
            .takeWhile { !it.id.startsWith(fromCommit) } //exclusive
            .map { Commit(it.title, listOf(it.id), name) }
            .toIterable()
}
```

Additional hints regarding the above code:

This is the GitlabCommit class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
private data class GitLabCommit(val id: String, val title: String)
```

The `client` is a properly initialized instance of `org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient.Builder`, that facilitates the token handling and URL encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Source of the exception: your outer use of `commits` doesn't have a `onErrorResume` clause.
Source of the endless loop: in abscence of an error in the inner `generate`, it will keep on looping, incrementing the `state` and concatenating an empty result.

I'd take a different approach than generate though: range + concatMap + takeWhile.

Something like this:

```
fun getCommits(fromCommit: String, toCommit: String): Iterable<String> =
    Flux.range(1, 1000) //tune the second parameter
            .concatMap { page -> client
                .get()
                .uri("/projects/{name}/repository/commits?page=$page&per_page=100")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux<GitLabCommit>()
                .doOnError({ LOGGER.warn("Could not retrieve commits for project '$name': ${it.message}")})
                .onErrorReturn(GitLabCommit("xxxxx", "Could not retrieve all commits for project '$name'"))
                .defaultIfEmpty(GitLabCommit("xxxxx", "Reached end of commit log."))
                // ^ we now have marker commits in case of error or end of log
            }
            //use the marker commits to short-circuit the range
            .takeWhile { !it.id.equals("xxxxx") } //end condition to cancel the range loop, doesn't include the xxxxx commits
            // The Gitlab API returns commits from newest to oldest
            .skipWhile { !it.id.startsWith(toCommit) } //inclusive
            .takeWhile { !it.id.startsWith(fromCommit) } //exclusive
            .map { Commit(it.title, listOf(it.id), name) }
            .toIterable()
```

We start from a range of up to 1000 pages, making a request for each page.

That could result in extraneous requests (say, if by the 100th page we already receive an empty response, there will be no more pages). You almost fixed this issue though:

We can use both `onErrorReturn` and `defaultIfEmpty` to create a marker commit that can then be used after the `concatMap` in a `takeWhile`.

Once the additional `takeWhile` sees the first `xxxxx` commit, it will trigger a cancellation that will propagate to concatMap/range, resulting in the range stopping emitting page numbers and thus stopping making extraneous requests.

Then you have your business logic `skipWhile`,`takeWhile` and `map`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Your first suggestions solved the problem. I will also check out your alternative as well, comment on it and accept your answer then!

Comment: I tried implementing your other suggestion, but there are issues with variable scoping and braces don't match. I couldn't resolve it myself, can you please have another look?

Comment: edited, should be better now provided you have a `client` variable in scope outside the function (like in your original snippet)